# How to write a java code to edit a agent in perforce and then checkout and submit

Tags: java, perforce

I want the java code to edit an agent and then do checkout and submit in perforce.

I know how to read the file and edit the file.

Required code - For checking out and submit.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java API:  https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4java-javadoc/

but for simple cases you're better off just calling out to the `p4` executable IMO.

```
p4 edit YOURFILE
p4 submit -d "your description"
```